# Spring XML configuration - how to define Instant, BigDecimal, ... parameters?

Tags: java, spring

How do I specify a constructor argument that is not a primitive value (or a simple type like a String) but still a class part of the Java library in the XML configuration file ?

The XML works so far for me for simple values, e.g.

```
<bean id="foo" class="app.model.provider.IFoo">
    <constructor-arg name="bar" value="baz"/>
</bean>
```

How do I define a dependency that requires e.g. a java.time.Instant instance in its constructor?

Comment: That depends. What value of `Instant` do you want to provide?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis for example I have a class that asks a start and end date: new HistoricalData(Instant.parse("2015-07-24T17:10:00Z"), Instant.parse("2015-07-24T18:00:00Z")); which I thought could be configurable in the XML file.

Comment: Use(static) factory methods.

Comment: Thanks, so I guess each Instant is a bean then. And how would you define a bean that requires a BigDecimal constructor parameter. e.g. new Foo(new BigDecimal("2.5")); ?

Comment: Nameless beans perhaps. That `BigDecimal` constructor takes a String.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring allows you to use [factory methods](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-class-static-factory-method) to get instances.

Say you wanted to do the equivalent of

```
Instant.now();
```

you would use

```
<bean id="anInstant" class="java.time.Instant" factory-method="now"/>
```

If you want to do

```
Instant.parse("2015-07-24T17:10:00Z")
```

you would use

```
<bean id="anInstant" class="java.time.Instant" factory-method="parse">
    <constructor-arg value="2015-07-24T17:10:00Z" />
</bean>
```

However, I wouldn't create accessible `Instant` beans. If you need to pass them to some other bean's constructor, provide them directly, without names

```
<bean id="example" class="com.example.Example">
    <constructor-arg name="startTime">
        <bean class="java.time.Instant" factory-method="parse">
            <constructor-arg value="2015-07-24T17:10:00Z" />
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```